# Shiny do something when user has successfully downloaded a file

Tags: r, shiny

I want to update a database whenever a user has downloaded some data (for example, each dataset in the app below should be downloaded only once).

Is there a way to know in shiny if a download was successful?

A quick MWE would be this, however, the dataset is removed from the list whenever the download button is clicked, not when the actual file is downloaded. Ie when I abort the download in the browser window, it still removes the file.

```
library(shiny)

datasets <- c("mtcars", "anscombe", "airmiles", "attenu", "airquality")
  
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("dataset", "Dataset to Download", choices = datasets),
  downloadButton("download", "Download Dataset")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() paste0(input$dataset, ".csv"),
    content = function(file) {
      cat(sprintf("Downloading Dataset %s\n", input$dataset))
      
      write.csv(get(input$dataset), file)
      
      # remove the currently selected value from the selection;
      # logical error here: this is also executed when the download is aborted
      datasets <<- setdiff(datasets, input$dataset)
      updateSelectInput(inputId = "dataset", choices = datasets)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I don't think you'll find a "shiny-only" solution to this. You might want to check [related JS questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-a-browser-receives-a-file-download).